# Sort spills to tempdb due to varchar(max)

Tags: sql-server, performance, tempdb, cardinality-estimates, query-performance

On a server with 32GB we are running SQL Server 2014 SP2 with a max memory of 25GB we have two tables, here you find a simplified structure of both tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Settings](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [resourceId] [int] NULL,
    [typeID] [int] NULL,
    [remark] [varchar](max) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Settings] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Resources](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [resourceUID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Resources] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

with following non-clustered indexes:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_UID] ON [dbo].[Resources]
(
    [resourceUID] ASC
)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Test] ON [dbo].[Settings]
(
    [resourceId] ASC,
    [typeID] ASC
)
```

The database is configured with `compatibility level` 120.

When I run this [query](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJZY5j3f4) there are spills to `tempdb`. 
This is how I execute the query:

```
exec sp_executesql N'
select r.id,remark
FROM Resources r
inner join Settings on resourceid=r.id
where resourceUID=@UID
ORDER BY typeID',
N'@UID int',
@UID=38
```

If don't select the `[remark]` field no spills occurs. My first reaction was that the spills occurred due to the low number of estimated rows on the nested-loop operator.

So I add 5 datetime and 5 integer columns to the settings table and add them to my select statement. When I execute the query no spills are happening.

Why are the spills only happening when `[remark]` is selected? It has probably something to do with the fact that this is a `varchar(max)`.
What can I do to avoid spilling to `tempdb`?

Adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the query makes no difference.

Comment: May be you can try `select r.id, LEFT(remark, 512)` (or whatever sensible substring length might be).

Comment: @Forrest: I'm trying to reproduce the data needed to simulate the problem. At first sight it has to do with the low estimate of the nested loop. In my dummy data the estimated number of rows is much higher and no spilling is happening

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are going to be several possible workarounds here.

You can [manually adjust](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3107401/new-query-memory-grant-options-are-available-min-grant-percent-and-max) the memory grant, though I probably wouldn't go that route.

You can also use a CTE and TOP to push the sort lower, before grabbing the max length column. It will look something like below.

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT TOP 1000000000 r.ID, s.ID AS ID2, s.typeID
FROM Resources r
inner join Settings s on resourceid=r.id
where resourceUID=@UID
ORDER BY s.typeID
)
SELECT c.ID, ca.remark
FROM CTE c
CROSS APPLY (SELECT remark FROM dbo.Settings s WHERE s.id = c.ID2) ca(remark)
ORDER BY c.typeID
```

Proof-of-concept dbfiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b7fc96cc987a1ece7b487392ed033750).
Sample data would still be appreciated!

If you want to read an excellent analysis by Paul White, [read here.](https://sqlkiwi.blogspot.com/2011/02/advanced-tsql-tuning-why-internals-knowledge-matters.html)

Answer (score 7):

> Why are the spills only happening when [remark] is selected?

The spill is happening when you include that column because you don't get a big enough memory grant for the large string data being sorted.

You don't get a big enough memory grant because the actual number of rows is 10x more than the estimated number of rows (1,302 actual vs 126 estimated).

Why is the estimate off?  Why does SQL Server think there's only one row in dbo.Settings with a `resourceid` of 38?

It could be a statistics issue, which you can check by running `DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS('dbo.Settings', 'IX_Test')` and see the counts for that histogram step.  But the execution plan seems to indicate that the stats are as complete and up-to-date as they could be.

Since stats aren't helping, your best bet is probably a query rewrite - which [Forrest](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/87836/forrest) has covered in [his answer.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/227290/6141)

Answer (score 4):

To me it appears that the `where` clause in the query is giving the issue, and is the cause of the low estimates, even if `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` is used.

I created some test data, and in the end came up with two solutions, storing the `ID` field from `resources` in either a variable (if it is always unique) or a temp table, if we can have more than one `ID`'s.

**Base test records**

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @i int= 1;
WHILE @i <= 10000
BEGIN
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Settings]([resourceId],[typeID],remark)
VALUES(@i,@i,'KEPT THESE VALUES OUT BECAUSE IT WOULD CLUTTER THE EXAMPLES, VALUES OVER 8000 Chars entered here'); -- 23254 character length on each value
INSERT INTO  [dbo].[Resources](resourceUID)
VALUES(@i);
SET @i += 1;
END
```

**Insert the 'Seek' values, as to get to the same approximate resultset as OP (1300 records)**

```
INSERT INTO  [dbo].[Settings]([resourceId],[typeID],remark)
VALUES(38,38,'KEPT THESE VALUES OUT BECAUSE IT WOULD CLUTTER THE EXAMPLES, VALUES OVER 8000 Chars entered here')
GO 1300
```

**Change compat & Update statistics to match OP**

```
ALTER DATABASE StackOverflow SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 120;
UPDATE STATISTICS settings WITH FULLSCAN;
UPDATE STATISTICS resources WITH FULLSCAN;
```

**Original query**

```
exec sp_executesql N'
select r.id
FROM Resources r
inner join Settings on resourceid=r.id
where resourceUID=@UID
ORDER BY typeID',
N'@UID int',
@UID=38
```

My estimates are even [worse](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1ev2gTf4), with one estimated row, while 1300 are returned.
And like OP stated, it does not matter if I add `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`

**An important thing to note, is that when we get rid of the where clause the estimates are 100% correct, which is expected since we are using all data in both tables.**

*I forced the indexes just to make sure we use the same ones as in the previous query, to prove the point*

```
exec sp_executesql N'
select r.id,remark
FROM Resources r with(index([IX_UID]))
inner join Settings WITH(INDEX([IX_Test])) 
on resourceid=r.id
ORDER BY typeID',
N'@UID int',
@UID=38
```

As expected, [good](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ByHT6xpME) estimates.

**So, what could we change to get better estimates but still seek on our values?**

IF @UID is unique, as in the example OP gave, we could put the single `id` that was returned from `resources` in a variable, then seek on that variable with an OPTION(RECOMPILE)

```
DECLARE @UID int =38 , @RID int;
SELECT @RID=r.id from 
Resources r where resourceUID = @UID;

SELECT @uid, remark 
from Settings 
where resourceId = @uid 
Order by typeID
OPTION(RECOMPILE);
```

Which gives 100% accurate [estimates](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkzDCeaM4)

**But what if there are multiple resourceUID's in resources?**

*add some test data*

```
INSERT INTO Resources(ResourceUID)
VALUES (38);
go 50
```

**This could be resolved with a temp table**

```
CREATE TABLE #RID (id int)
DECLARE @UID int =38 
INSERT INTO #RID
SELECT r.id 
from 
Resources r where resourceUID = @UID

SELECT @uid, remark 
from Settings  s
INNER JOIN #RID r
ON r.id =s.resourceId
Order by typeID
OPTION(RECOMPILE)

DROP TABLE #RID
```

Again with accurate [estimates](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1yq1-TzN).

This was done with my own dataset,YMMV.

---

**Written with sp_executesql**

*With a variable*

```
exec sp_executesql N'
DECLARE  @RID int;
    SELECT @RID=r.id from 
    Resources r where resourceUID = @UID;

    SELECT @uid, remark 
    from Settings 
    where resourceId = @uid 
    Order by typeID
    OPTION(RECOMPILE);',
N'@UID int',
@UID=38
```

*With a temp table*

```
exec sp_executesql N'

CREATE TABLE #RID (id int)

INSERT INTO #RID
SELECT r.id 
from 
Resources r where resourceUID = @UID

SELECT @uid, remark 
from Settings  s
INNER JOIN #RID r
ON r.id =s.resourceId
Order by typeID
OPTION(RECOMPILE)

DROP TABLE #RID',
N'@UID int',
@UID=38
```

*Still 100% correct estimates on my test*