# Nested Loop has very low estimates due to skewed data

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2016, cardinality-estimates, query-performance

On SQL Server 2016 SP2 we have a [query](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkM2EvEQV) that has a very low estimate on the nested loop operator. Due to the low estimate this query also spills to tempdb.

If I'm correct SQL Server 2014+ uses *Coarse Histogram Estimation* to calculate the estimated number of rows on a join.
But when I execute the query, SQL Server uses the *density vector* to calculate the number of estimated rows.
Is SQL Server only using the *Coarse Histogram Estimation* if there is no `where` clause?

Normally I would use *filtered statistics* to improve estimations when I have a table with skewed data. But in this case that doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way to improve the estimations on the nested loop?

Using following code you can reproduce the data:

```
create table MyTable
(
    id int identity,
    field varchar(50),
    constraint  pk_id primary  key clustered (id)
)
go

create table SkewedTable
(
    id int identity,
    startdate datetime,
    myTableId int,
    remark varchar(50),
    constraint  pk_id primary  key clustered (id)
)

set nocount on

insert into MyTable select top 1000 [name] from master..spt_values
go

insert into SkewedTable select GETDATE(),FLOOR(RAND()*(1000))+1,REPLICATE(N'A',FLOOR(RAND()*(40))+1)
go 1000

insert into SkewedTable select GETDATE(),FLOOR(RAND()*(1000))+1,REPLICATE(N'A',FLOOR(RAND()*(40))+1)
go 

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_field] ON [dbo].[MyTable]([field] ASC)
go

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_mytableid] ON [dbo].[SkewedTable]([myTableId] ASC)
go

--95=varchar in sys.messages
set nocount off

;with cte as
( 
    select GETDATE() as startdate ,95 as myTableId, REPLICATE(N'B',FLOOR(RAND()*(40))+1) as remark
    union all
    select * from cte
)
insert into skewedtable select top 40000 * from cte
option(maxrecursion 0)
go

update statistics mytable with fullscan
go

update statistics skewedtable with fullscan
go
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Normally I would use *filtered statistics* to improve estimations when I have a table with skewed data. But in this case that doesn't seem to work.

You should find the following filtered statistic helpful:

```
CREATE STATISTICS [stats id (field=varchar)]
ON dbo.MyTable (id)
WHERE field = 'varchar'
WITH FULLSCAN;
```

This gives the optimizer information about the **distribution** of `id` values that *match* `field = 'varchar'`, giving a much better selectivity estimate for the join:

[image: Actual execution plan]

The [execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJdCrOEQE) above shows exactly correct estimates with the filtered statistic, leading the optimizer to choose a hash join (for cost reasons).

This *distribution* information is much more important than the exact method used by the estimator to match the join histograms (fine or [coarse alignment](https://sqlperformance.com/2018/11/sql-optimizer/histogram-coarse-alignment)), or even the general assumptions (e.g. simple join, base containment).

If you can't do that, your options are broadly as outlined in answer to your previous question [Sort spills to tempdb due to varchar(max)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/227288). My preference would probably be an intermediate temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

**Completely agree with the filtered index, this answer is added to expand on the other option that @PaulWhite mentioned, to use an intermediate temp table and consequentially get rid of the `SORT` operator**

**You could add an index or change the existing index:**

```
CREATE INDEX IX_SkewedTable_MytableId_startdate
ON SkewedTable(myTableId,startdate)
INCLUDE(remark);
```

**Insert the values in an intermediate temp table**

```
CREATE TABLE  #temp2(param int);
INSERT INTO  #temp2(param)
SELECT t.id 
FROM mytable t 
WHERE t.field = 'varchar';
```

[image]

**Add an index on the temp table**

```
CREATE INDEX IX_ID on #temp2(param);
```

**And then use a CTE to remove the sort operator from the query plan**

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
select TOP(999999999999)
s.myTableId,s.id,s.remark from 
SkewedTable s
order by startdate
)
SELECT s.id , s.remark
from CTE  s
INNER JOIN #temp2 
on s.myTableId = #temp2.param
OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```

As mentioned by @Forrest to push the sort lower [Here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/227288/sort-spills-to-tempdb-due-to-varcharmax)

**Result:**

[image]

*Which removes the sort operator.*

Comment: Top 100 percent hasn't worked in ages - the optimizer throw it out. You're better off using a number like the int or big int max.

Comment: @ErikDarling Changed it, thanks for the feedback